# I want to extract part of a line using sed and backreference

Tags: ubuntu, sed, reference

```
 1.The Greater Company :(Ranked 2) 
 5.United Taxi Service :(Ranked 3) 
31.The Cacao Company :(Ranked 4) 
40.Monster Inc. :(Ranked 5)
55.Afala, Industrial Strength :(Ranked 6) 
60.The North Company :(Ranked 7)
```

I want to display just the company number and company name. I do not want the rest of the line to be displayed.

```
 1.The Greater Company  
 5.United Taxi Service 
31.The Cacao Company  
40.Monster Inc. 
55.Afala, Industrial Strength 
60.The North Company
```

I can do this by sed 's/: .* //' filename.txt. How would I use this pattern with back reference so I can achieve the above result. The pattern that I want to match would be ([0-9]* .* :).

Comment: It *appears* that you're *removing* the ranking, not "extracting the company number and rank"; can you clarify your goal vs your output?

Comment: I edited it. What i meant was just have the result being displayed like that. I can do this with sed by using sed 's/: .*//' filename.txt, but i want to know how to achieve this by using backreference.

Comment: When somebody asks “How do I do X?”, we always ask “What have you tried?”  Have you read any documentation?  What part of it did you not understand?  And is that a `:)` smiley face at the end of your question?  Or are you saying that the pattern that you want to match is `[0-9]* .* :`, but you’re putting it in parentheses ***instead of*** quotes — this, when the input text contains parentheses (but not quotes).  That is very confusing. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  What’s more confusing: you say that you want to match ``[0-9]*  …``, but your data don’t have a space after the number. And you say that you want to match ``… :``, but your sample output shows that you don’t want to match the colon (`:`), just everything up to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all of the lines begin with `[0-9]*` there's no need to match it explicitly: just capture up to (but not including) the `:` delimiter

```
sed 's/\(^[^:]*\) :.*/\1/' file
  1.The Greater Company
  5.United Taxi Service
  31.The Cacao Company
  40.Monster Inc.
  55.Afala, Industrial Strength
  60.The North Company
```

Comment: could you explain the command and how the back referencing works

Comment: @Rashad the pattern between `\(` and `\)` is *captured*, and then it is *backreferenced* as `\1`. See for example [Regular Expression Reference: Capturing Groups and Backreferences](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html)

Comment: You can omit the second colon: `sed 's/\(^[^:]*\) .*/\1/'`